# Bin Packing / Knapsack / Perfect Sum Problem With Target Item Quantities

Tags: knapsack-problem, subset-sum, bin-packing

1. There is a set of items, each with a specific weight
2. There are a number of bins each with a limited weight capacity
3. For each item there is a target percentage of its quantity across all bins (e.g. if there are 4 items, 10% item 1, 50% item 2, 20% item 3, 20% item 4)
4. Items can be repeated to pack the bins

I need to find the packing solution such that:

- there is zero capacity left in the bins
- the resulting item quantities are ***as close as possible*** to the target percentages per item

The ideas that come to mind at the moment are a sort of brute force perfect sum algorithm that finds all possible combinations of items to perfectly pack the bins and then returns the one that is closest to the target percentages. This idea of "closest to target percentages" can be defined as the least mean square error to the input target percentages. However, this solution will take a long time for numerous / large bins.

An unbounded, multi-dimensional, multiple Knapsack problem also comes to mind where capacity is one dimension, and the target percentages per item are the others. Not sure about this.

Any help / ideas would be greatly appreciated!